# React Props Changing Unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and React Bootstrap to create my application. I am attempting to create a Modal from Bootstrap that acts as a config window. Its initial data is passed down as a prop, then the current data is stored in state so that I can have the option to close without saving, and can revert back to the initial data if needed. However, the props seem to be getting updated on change of a Bootstrap text input, and I cannot figure out why.

This is the code of my input control:

```
<Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.localData.rootFilesystem}
                                                  onChange={(event) => {
                                                      let editedData = this.state.localData;
                                                      editedData.rootFilesystem = event.target.value;
                                                      this.setState(editedData);
                                                  }} />
```

`localData` is initially filled in the constructor with

```
this.state = { localData: this.props.projectData }
```

Adding in a `console.log(this.props.projectData);` to the form control's `onChange` shows that the props are being updated on change.

Why would this be? From what I can tell, there is no reason that any props should be updated since the only actions in `onChange` affect only the component's state.

Comment: What is in your projectData field of props? Does it contains rootFilesystem property?

Comment: @DharaCharola Yes, the projectData is an object containing all of the project's data, and rootFilesystem is one of its fields.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly modifying the state object here:

```js
let editedData = this.state.localData;
editedData.rootFilesystem = event.target.value;
```

Consdering you set `this.state.localData` equal to `this.props.projectData` when you write `this.state = { localData: this.props.projectData }`, and both contain a `rootFilesystem` property, perhaps there is some interference there.

Try copying `this.state.localData` instead of referring to it.  Like this:

```js
let editedData = {...this.state.localData}
```

Without seeing more to the code, this is the only thing I can tell may be the problem.

Comment: A combination of this and Dhara's answer solved the issue, thank you to both of you!

Comment: I did that, but, as I have a new account it told me that it won't show up publicly until I have 15 reputation

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, and thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with destructure

```
onChange={(event) => {
    let {localData} = this.state;
    localData.rootFilesystem = event.target.value;
    this.setState({localData}); }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is still ending with the props changing...

Comment: Can you prepare the sandbox or any working example? It will help to go through the code and flow

Comment: Combining this with using the spread operator as suggested in Seth's answer solved the issue, thank you both!
```let localData = { ...this.state.localData };
                                                          localData.rootFilesystem = event.target.value;
                                                          this.setState({localData});```